# Backtracking using loops in java?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, nested-if

Here's the gist of my code and it's function. It's a pick-where-you-go game to choose your path. For example, if you choose path a at the start, you get to choose between path d and e, and if you chose d you can move to f and g and so on.

I want to add backtracking. For instance, if I choose a in the beginning and go all the way to f, I want to be able to go back to d and have the choice between f and g again, or go all the way back to the starting point and choose b.

My initial thought was to use something to tell the code to go back to a certain line of code when I need to backtrack, but there's no goto in java to my understanding. I have an inkling to use loops. (I'm thinking while loops in particular.) I cannot figure out HOW to structure the loops to backtrack.

Here's my code:

```
public class PathGame {

public static void main (String[] args) {

String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hello! Welcome to my paths! What is your name, adventurer?");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Well then " + name + ", here's how this works...some generic instructions");

String startingChoice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose your path, a, b, or c.");

if (startingChoice.equals("a")){
String aChoice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose path d or path e");

if (aChoice.equals("d")) {
    String dExamineChoice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("path f or g?");
   if (dExamineChoice.equals("f")) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, name + "...!");
   }
   else if (dExamineChoice.equals("g")) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Stuff g");
   }
}
else if (aChoice.equals("e")) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Stuff e");
}
else if (aChoice.equals("goBack")) {
    ///Backtrack back to start
}
}
else if (startingChoice.equals("b")) {
String bChoice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Path h or i?");
if (bChoice.equals("h")) {
    String hChoice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Path j, k, or l?");
    if (hChoice.equals("j")) {
        String jExamine = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("m or n?");
        if (jExamine.equals("m")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Stuff m");
        }
        else if (jExamine.equals("n")) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Stuff n");
        }
    }
    else if (hChoice.equals("k")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Stuff k");
    }
    else if (hChoice.equals("l")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Stuff l");
    }
    }
else if (bChoice.equals("i")) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Stuff i");
}
    }
}
}
```

Comment: you'll need to store the possible choices in a graph data structure: starting at a root node the edges are to node `a`, `b` and `c`, from `a` there are edges to `d` and `e` etc... Then the user choices are just a list of traversed nodes in this graph (i.e. a path). to go back just remove the last entry from the list.

Comment: You'll have to forgive me, but I am unfamiliar with that kind of graph data structure. How would I go about that? I get what your saying on a practical level, I just don't know how to translate that into code, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Backtracking can be achieved with recursion. However, since you wanted the iterative approach. You can apply the same concept using a stack. Every time you visit a new square, push the current state into the stack. When you need to backtrack (for example you are in a dead end), pop out from the stack.

If your intention is to create something like a maze runner, you may want to record the visited squares.

And yes, you should be using a while-loop to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Make an option back for each starting choice, such that when the user selects that option startingChoice is set to the letter you want to go back to.

Comment: Perhaps I'm mistaken, but without a loop, wouldn't I just be stuck doing ifs upon ifs ad infinitum? I feel like I would have to rewrite the code over and over again. Unless I'm missing what your saying, which I admittedly likely am.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you could do this.

**The extendable way** would be to use a graph data structure. You could use something like [JGraphT](http://jgrapht.org/) or [TinkerPop](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/). But that's assuming you want something really fancy. A graph would let you treat the whole path selection (traversal) very generically. It would let you design all sorts of paths and backtracking would simply be keeping track of where you came from.

**The faster way** would be to use a `Stack` data structure. Everytime you make a choice add that choice to your stack. So your current position is always stored at the top of the stack. When you backtrack just pop off the top of the stack and try again. For example:

```
public static void main(String []){
    Stack<String> myPath = new Stack<>();
    while(detinationNotReached){
        myPath = goSomewhere(myPath);
    }
}
public Stack goSomewhere(Stack<String> myPath){
    String currentPosition = myPath.peek();
    String choice = getChoice(currentPosition);
    switch(choice){
        case "a":
            myPath.push("a");
        break;
        ... //Other choices
        case "back":
            myPath.pop(); // This effectively backtracks.
        break;
    }
    return myPath
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you store your possibilities in a graph data structure (i.e. a [half-edge data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_connected_edge_list)):

```
class Edge {
    public final Node end;
    public Edge(Node end) { this.end = end; }
}

class Node {
    public final int id;
    public final List<Edge> edges;
    public Node(int id, List<Edge> edges) { this.id = id; this.edges = Collections.unmodifiableList(edges); }
}

class Graph {
    private final ArrayList<ArrayList<Edge>> halfEdges = new ArrayList<>();
    private final ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();

    public Node addNode() {
        ArrayList<Edge> edges = new ArrayList<>();
        Node node = new Node(nodes.size(), edges);
        halfEdges.add(edges);
        nodes.add(node);
        return node;
    }

    public Edge addEdge(Node from, Node to) {
        assert nodes.contains(from) && nodes.contains(to);
        Edge edge = new Edge(to);
        halfEdges.get(from.id).add(edge);
        return edge;
    }
}
```

You'd use it like this:

```
class Game
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Graph graph = new Graph();
        Node root = graph.addNode();
        Node a = graph.addNode();
        graph.addEdge(root, a);
        Node b = graph.addNode();
        graph.addEdge(root, b);
        Node c = graph.addNode();
        graph.addEdge(root, c);
        Node d = graph.addNode();
        graph.addEdge(a, d);
        Node e = graph.addNode();
        graph.addEdge(a, e);
        // ...

        // main loop
        ArrayList<Node> path = new ArrayList<>();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        while(true) {
            if(path.isEmpty())
                path.add(root);
            Node pos = path.get(path.size() - 1);
            builder.setLength(0);
            builder.append("At ").append(pos.id).append(", choices: back");
            for(Edge out : pos.edges)
                builder.append(", ").append(out.end.id);
            System.out.println(builder.toString());
            // handle input: add chosen node to path or remove last entry if "back"
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

You can add any kind of data to a `Node` or an `Edge`, like an actual name for the choice to display (instead of `id`) etc...